# iOS 7 is there a way to know when the MKTileOverlay is finished loading tiles?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mktileoverlay

I would like to implement a zoom effect on the map (which I already have figured out), but after the the MKTileOverlay is finished loading the tiles. Is there anyway to know when those tiles have finished loading? I have tried all the other mapView methods and nothing seems to wait until the overlay loads before it runs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the only thing that I have found that works is a timer.

Comment: Care to elaborate? How does a timer solve this issue?

Comment: @Stavash The timer doesn't necessarily solve the issue. Just a work around for the particular issue. I just created a timer to run a method after the maximum amount of time I figured it would take to load the overlay. I sure there is a more correct way to do this... I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `MKMapViewDelegate` method:

[`mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:fullyRendered:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap%3afullyRendered%3a)

Comment: When I tried using this method it always ran after the actual map finished rendering, without regard to the overlays. Have you had a different experience?

Comment: @Cedric I have encountered the same behavior.